# Can't understand how Spring Boot manage integration tests with maven. Is it uses failsafe plugin or not?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, integration-testing

I'm trying to undestand how spring boot manage the integration tests.

Basically, in any project that have a Integration Test, the responsable plugin for that is the maven **failsafe** plugin. By default, it executes all classes that have the suffix **IT**. Per example: `MyServiceIT.java`.

Well, here is the first problem. Most of the examples I found of Spring Boot running integration tests (even in the official documentation or Spring blog) the test classes have the sufix **Test**. So, I understand that they will run by the maven **surefire** plugin, what is not desirable for a Integration Test.

But the confusion is not over.

The spring boot maven plugin documentation [says nothing about the failsafe plugin](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/usage.html) if the objective is run integration tests. But, if you would like to skip them, [the failsafe plugin appears](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/examples/it-skip.html) in the documentation.

For now I'm using the maven failsafe plugin with suffix **IT** in my spring boot integration tests, ignoring them on the surefire:

```
<plugin>
    <!-- for unit tests -->
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>**/*IT.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>

<plugin>
    <!--for integrations tests-->
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <skipITs>${skipITs}</skipITs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

But another coworker are using the suffix `Test` in his Spring Boot integration tests (in another project) and claim to me that is the right suffix to use¹.

So... I'm doing something wrong? How this "strange" setup from Spring Boot works for integration tests?

*¹. Sonar are able to get his test coverage and my tests are not. We are using the Cobertura maven plugin. I think the reason for that is that his tests are running over surefire plugin, but over failsafe plugin I need extra configuration on pom.xml and, maybe, on Sonar too.*

Comment: This Spring web site also solves this problem using your approach: [Integration Testing with the Maven Cargo plugin] (https://www.baeldung.com/integration-testing-with-the-maven-cargo-plugin) so basically, you are not wrong.

Answer (score 0):

i don't think you need to use the fail-safe plug-in. the spring-boot-starter-parent reference that spring boot docs tells you to use has everything that anyone could even think about using including the kitchen sink in there.

the failsafe plug-in is one way to do integration tests. that leaves some manual configuration on your part.

but if you're using spring boot you should use the built-in facilities that come with spring boot. after all that's the whole point of using spring boot. they do a lot for you. i would suspect the reason you don't see much in the spring boot docs about the fail-safe plug-in mentioned in spring docs is that they don't expect people to use that.

see the following tutorial. it's simplistic but it's a good starting place:

[Baeldung Tutorial on Spring Boot Testing](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-testing)